# Time complexity of an algorithm, dividing a problem of size (n) into 2 problems of size (n-1)

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, divide-and-conquer

Algorithm B divides the problem into 2 sub-problems of size n-1, solves them recursively, then combine them in constant time.

What is the time complexity of the algorithm B?

Answer (score 1):

well try to image the calls as nodes of a tree:
it's a tree (binary tree), where both branch will have a height of `n-1` (because of the recursive call with size `n-1`), so the root node will have a left branch with height `n-1`, and a right branch with height `n-1`.

Now so you have 2 full tree with each "path" long `n-1`, so you have 2 trees on height `n-1`, which will have `2^(n-1)` nodes, so the total number of calls is:

```
2^(n-1)      +      2^(n-1)       +       1  
left branch         right branch          root node

= 2 * 2^(n-1) + 1
= 2^n (the +1 is negligible)
```

Comment: So, I am counting nodes? Why is that? And the answer above is a bit different than yours?

Comment: @drstress the nodes are the recursive calls, you start with one call (which is the root node), which produce 2 calls with an input of size n-1, so you will have 2 branches with input size = n-1, which will produce other 2 branches each with n-2 and so on

Comment: So, the logic behind the master theorem is the same?

Comment: @drstress well the logic depends, this is a possible representation of it, but you can see it in other ways, it depends on how you see things... (a+b)^2 can be seen as (a+b)(a+b), which explains the "+2ab" to many, but others see that as a square of side (a+b), and if you have a look to the area of that square, you will see 2 square (with area a^2 and b^2) and 2 rectangle with area a*b, and so they see where the +2ab comes from... as i said, this is only a representation, the same for the answer made by Daniel

Comment: I can't connect this with how an actual computer works… Are we talking about the speed when we say time complexity?

Comment: @drstress every time you call that function, for what you are saying, other than calling recursively itself, it does something in constant time, so is like if you are adding every time you call it, 1, (or C if you prefer), then you will have that the complexity is O(C * number_of_calls) = O(C* 2^n) which by definition of big-O notation, is O(2^n)

Answer (score 0):

Basically what it seems to me is:

```
                 n                     layer 0        
              ／    ＼                 
           ／          ＼             
        (n-1)          (n-1)           layer 1
       ／   ＼        ／   ＼          
    (n-2)   (n-2)  (n-2)   (n-2)       layer 2
     / \     / \    / \     / \
   ..............................        ...
   | | | | .............. | | | |
   1 1 1 1                1 1 1 1      layer n - 1
```

The height (number of horizontal layers) is `n` and each layer `i` does `2^i` operations, so the complexity is:

```
2^0 + 2^1 + ... + 2^(n - 1) = 
∑ 2^i [i = 0, ..., n - 1] =
2^n - 1
```

So `O(2^n - 1)` = `O(2^n)`.

Comment: Why each layer does 2^i operations? And the answer below is a bit different than yours, is it the same?

Comment: Because, as you said, the algorithm receives an input of size `n` and divides it recursively in two inputs of size `n - 1`. The first layer receives the input of size `n` and breaks it in 2 inputs of size `n - 1`. Then, the second layer will work with these 2 inputs of size `n - 1` and break them into 2 inputs of size `n - 2` each (totalizing 4 inputs of size `n - 2`), and so on.

Comment: So it's easy to see that the first layer does 2^0 = 1 operation, the second will do 2^1 = 2 operations, the third, 2^2 = 4 operations, the forth, 2^3 = 8 operations, and so on. The last (n-th) layer will perform 2^(n - 1) operations.

Comment: Okay, I got it... So the total amount of dividing operations gives the time complexity in big O notation? And the question says combine them in constant time, what does that mean? What would change if it says combine them in linear time or time n^3 for example?

Comment: Yes, if you need to divide until it comes to a value of 1, then you need O(2^n) time to do that. Combining in constant time means you wont do any extra heavy operation when your recursion is coming back. If it wasn't constant (say it was linear), then the complexity could be O(n * 2^n) or something like that.

Comment: Take this function as an example and see how it behaves in a compiler:
`f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-1), if n > 1`, `f(n) = 1, if n = 1`. It merges both function calls with a `+`, which is constant. See the values and count the function calls for each `n`.

Comment: How will I try and analyze this with a compiler? How will I see the function calls?

Comment: Just put a print with a global counter to see how many times the function is called and the result.

Comment: Ah sorry I am asking again but every layer i does 2^(i - 1) operations or 2^(i) operations? Shouldn't layer 0 do 1 operation if it divides the problem into two, isn't that a single operation?

Comment: You are right, it's `2^i`, I was using the first layer as layer 1, but then I changed for layer 0 and I did this mistake. The answer is `2^i` operations for layer, considering dividing the problem in two as being a single operation.

Comment: And the nth layer shouldn't perform any operation at all? since it's all 1's?

Comment: Note that there is a problem to be solved. Dividing the problem in two subproblems doesn't solve the problem. The recursive solution means that something is done in the returning path of the recursive calls. The last layer won't perform the *dividing* operation, but it is supposed to do something. In the example I gave (`f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-1)`), the last layer will perform a lot of `+`s. Precisely, the layer `i`, in the returning step of the recursion, will perform `2^(i - 1)` operations of `+`.

Comment: Yes I realized that after writing… One last thing. The question asks which algorithm you would choose?   Algorith A: O(n^(2.6))  B: O(2^n)  C: O(n^3)